# How can I used a generic extension function in Kotlin for two type of data class mapper

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-methods

I have two data model classes and I want to use a generic extension function to map these classes and other classes.

**This is a sample of my code to map the two classes:**

```
fun HomeRequestBodyWithAuthQuery.Client.graphToDomain(): Client =
    Client(id = this.id, givenName = this.givenName)
```

I wrote this extension function but the return value has an error:

```
fun <G,  T> G.graphqlToDomain(): T  = T
```

[image]
how can I write a kotlin extension function for this work?

Comment: Where is G in your sample? As I see you have used Client.graphToDomain() and return a Client with mapping. like, T.graphToDomain(): T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your generic type as a parameter and return it.

```
fun <G, T> G.graphqlToDomain(t: T): T = t
```